# Deep link from Salesforce app to FSL app?

Tags: deep-linking

I'm trying to create a link to the FSL app, from the Salesforce app. 
Both in Android based apps only.

The link is to be added into a LWC component (could be a link/button/..., it doesn't matter). That LWC component is within the Saleforce app, the link needs to open up the FSL app.

I just can't work out how to create the link itself.
I've read the documentation on FSL deep linking and I know I have the schema correct as I can open the following from Slack on my phone for instance:
`com.salesforce.fieldservice://v1/WorkOrder/<myWoId>`

I'm at a loss on how to create the link itself however, in an HTML  tag.

I've read through posts on different forums and that one for instance refers to opening android apps from a web page:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773958/open-android-application-from-a-web-page
But then no idea what the action/host would be in this scenario?

Anyone has done this / know how to do this?
It seems very silly and according to Salesforce you can do it, I am completely missing the right incantation though...

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, Salesforce Mobile doesn't let you put links to apps in custom UI.
I've only tried in Flow, but I also found it was not possible. You will either need to write your own Local Action to invoke, or you can use an available package like this: https://englhardconsulting.com/flow-components-redirect-flow-record-id-and-url/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work for android, but iOS alludes me.  Check my question here, this might help you in your quest: [How to Deeplink FSL mobile App and Salesforce App](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/320918/how-to-deeplink-fsl-mobile-app-and-salesforce-app)